# replace a 'space' char in filename with an underscore

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files in a directory with 'spaces' in the filename.

How do I perform a bulk rename of all filenames with 'spaces' and replace them with an '_' char.

Looking at the other solutions, I've tried the following command w/o success:

> find . -name '* *' -exec rename ' ' '_' {} +

find: rename: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you using OS X? For some reason it doesn't come with `rename(1)`, which is normally distributed as part of perl.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ for file in *; do [ -f "$file" ] && ( mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -e 's/ /_/g')" ); done
```

Comment: This looks like the safest, most portable approach to me.  Magic syntax stuff is always a little sketchy and hard for someone else to understand what's going on; this answer uses one of the 2 obvious choices for "character substitution" -- the other being tr IE var=$(echo "$var" | tr ' ' _)

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct answer, but most you will get are wrong in one way or another. Most likely, they will not use find properly, and you might get stupid results if any filename contains a ^J.

Also if you have /lots/ of files, you probably don't want your script to spawn a sed or mv for each entry.

Here's a way to do it properly with basic Perl:

```
find . -print0 | \
  perl -e '$/="\000";' -ne '$o=$_;tr/ /_/;rename($o,$_);'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers.

I found this one liner that did the trick:

```
for i in *\ *; do if [ -f "$i" ]; then mv "$i" ${i// /_}; fi; done
```

Comment: So this is way off in the weeds but you need to quote both "$1" and "${i// /_}".  Also, that ${var///} stuff looks like a non-posix shell extension (bash perhaps)?